# How to post java collection to webservice in play framework

Tags: java, web-services, playframework-2.0

I have a custom java class `CustomInput` and I want to post `List<CustomInput>` objects to my java web service.

In play framework api, there is option to post using

```
ws.url(url).post()
```

where we can post either `String`, `jsonNode`

but i didn't find option to post any object or xml

My webservice signature looks like below

```
@POST
@Path(AppConstants.GET_ASSETS)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public String getAssets(
        final MyRequestType objReqType) throws MyCustomException {
```

Can anybody tell me how can i achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

I encourage you to accept Json as a possible format to consume.
That way, Jersey will be able to accept Json as your body and map it with your object (MyRequestType).

If you don't want to do that though, I'm afraid there is no way to provide an XML body to the post() method.

You have still the choice to find a Java library to make the Marshalling for you but I don't have any on the top of my head

Comment: @Thieriot i didn't find any way to pass java collection. So i used the WS.url().post(jsonNode) to pass my java collection. in my websservice resource class i converted the jsonNode to java object using jackson.Its working fine. Thanks for the inputs

Answer (score 0):

How is your Web service handling plural parameters?

A list like: "arg=value1&arg=value2"

Or is it SOAP?
(Or something else?)